# Qt Frame with movable border

Tags: qt, user-interface

This is probably me lacking in Google-fu.

I happen to be programming in PySide, but I assume that everyone names this feature the same across GUI toolkits.  It'll certainly use the Qt nomenclature.

What's the name of the widget, frame, or whatever, that lets you have an adjustable border between two frames?  Here's a screenshot from Argos -- I can grab the heavy vertical line and change the border between the "files" menu and the image window.

With a keyword, I can look it up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `QSplitter`. Just add the widgets inside with `addWidget(QWidget *widget)`

Comment: That's what I'm looking for!  For some reason one of my widgets isn't adjusting itself correctly, when a fixed QHBoxLayout allowed that.  But that's a different question.